# How can Martin and Jake afford their living?

Tags: plot-explanation, touch

In the TV series [Touch](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1821681), the main character Martin and his son Jake live in a very luxurious flat in New York. He is working security related at the JFK airport.

- How can he afford this flat in Season 1?
- In Season 2, he moves with Jake to Los Angeles and lives there in a flat, but is not working for money any more (beside as working for the online newspaper). How can he afford this?

If possible I am searching for a in-series answer for these questions since I might have missed an explanation for it.

(As it was revealed in Season 1, his wife worked at the wall street, but as of the beginning of the show, her death was more than 10 years ago. Hence the money from her work and for her dead is probably completly consumed.)

Comment: How do you know that she didn't buy the flat? How do you know that the money is all gone?

Comment: @Richard Good point that they might have bought the flat. But in that case, Martin might work at a better place than the airport (In Season 1 it is often seen that he has work to do and he does not enjoy it, like being the babysitter for a dog). Also, he did not plan to leave New York, and since there is a warrant against him, it is not likely that he can access his bank account (if there was money left).

Comment: If they've already explained that his family had money, that seems a strong explanation for his living situation. Out of universe, it's just a hell of a lot easier to film in a larger space so people often have out-sized houses and apartments that should cost them thousands of dollars a month to rent (q.v. Friends where Joey and Chandler live in a 2 bedroom apartment within walking distance of Central Park)